# How to call a function in wordpress plugin from another site

Tags: plugins, outside-wordpress

I create a plugin and install it in any wordpress sites.
For any reason I need to call a function on those plugin from another site (not wordpress site).

I've already try to using [cURL](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) and [file_get_contents](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) to call the function, in some wordpress site it's worked well, but in some another wordpress site it's not working.

It's failed on calling the function because the wordpress site has the redirect URL or the wordpress site has another plugins installed like captcha, security, etc.

These are the code/function in my plugins:

```
Class Myplugin{

 ..........

  function get_wp_version(){
    // to do
  }
  
  function call_api(){
    if($_GET['get_wp_version'] && $_GET['token']){
       $wp_version = $this->get_wp_version();
       echo $wp_version;
    }
  }
........
}
```

And these are the code that I used to call the function from another site:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://mysite.com/?call_api=get_wp_version&token=xxx');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FRESH_CONNECT, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 0);
$curl_msg = curl_exec($ch);
```

Any help will be appreciated!

Oops, typo! The functin of my plugin should be like this:

```
Class Myplugin{

 ..........

  function get_wp_version(){
    // to do
  }

  function call_api(){
    if($_GET['call_api'] && $_GET['token']){
      if($_GET['call_api'] == 'get_wp_version'){
        $wp_version = $this->get_wp_version();
        echo $wp_version;
      }
    }
  }
........
}
```

Comment: What is the question? If security measures are blocking your access then you need to refine them or use something else like XML-RPC

Comment: My question is how can my curl script can bypass the redirect-url or the captcha. So I can get the results from the function that I call.

Comment: If you could bypass a security plugin there would not have been much reason to use it at all.....

Comment: Yes that what I want but I still doesn't know how to bypass any security of those plugins. Do you have any suggestion on what should I do?

Answer (score 4):

There are two way you can implement this

### 1. Use the AJAX API

This is the fastest way of doing it. Just register an ajax action and use that action url to send requests.

**Example**

```
add_action('wp_ajax_api-call', 'wpse_156943_ajax_api_handle_request');

function wpse_156943_ajax_api_handle_request(){
    // security check validation

    // do whatever you want to do
}
```

The url for the request will be like `http://example.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=api-call`

### 2. Create an URL Endpoint

Create a lot user friendly endpoint. For example `http://example.com/my-api`

**Example**

```
add_action( 'wp_loaded', 'wpse156943_internal_rewrites' );
function wpse156943_internal_rewrites(){
    add_rewrite_rule( 'my-api$', 'index.php?my-api=1', 'top' );
}

add_filter( 'query_vars', 'wpse156943_internal_query_vars' );
function wpse156943_internal_query_vars( $query_vars ){
    $query_vars[] = 'my-api';
    return $query_vars;
}

add_action( 'parse_request', 'wpse156943_internal_rewrites_parse_request' );
function wpse156943_internal_rewrites_parse_request( &$wp ){

    if (!array_key_exists( 'my-api', $wp->query_vars ) ) {
        return;
    }

    // security and validation 

    // do whatever you want to do

    die();
}
```

Hope it helps :)